# How to fix 'a:hover' white space on FontAwesome icons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, hover, font-awesome

I am using Font Awesome 4.2.0 icons and the `a:hover` shows the `background-color` as `white` which is expected, but when I tried to suppress the `white` color on the `a` tag to the size of the inside icon, it refused to change (gets smaller) when `margin`, `padding` and `height` is set to `0`. However, the `border-radius` will take effect, but it's not good enough.

```
#social-media-icons > a{
    color:inherit;
    /*border-radius:100% 100% 100% 100%;*/
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:0; 
}
```

How do I suppress the size of the `a` tag to only show the color `white` inside the Font Awesome icon?

Here's the code in a Bootstrap environment: [Bootply Code Editor](http://www.bootply.com/A41vuEYTbY)

Comment: not sure what your question is, maybe I'm a bit slow today but I'm not getting anything at all off your question, so please rephrase it for me: What do you expect it to happen when you hover? change size? change icon color? keep icon color but add a background?

Comment: Sorry, in a visual concept, I only want the bird (twitter, speaking of all the icons) to change to white and neglect any other white color outside of the icon. Right now, there's white color on the bird and the outside of the icon which I do not want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the font awesome icon without the square and style a square with css -  this will allow you to change the font color of the icon itself while leaving the square the same color. **[demo](http://www.bootply.com/r64Xl0noSM)**

```
#social-media-icons i {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 42px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #3f729b;
}

#social-media-icons i:hover {
    background:#25445d;
    color: #25445d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I'm a bit closer now. An update has been made to show my current progress: http://www.bootply.com/theamazingknight/A41vuEYTbY. Do you know how to get rid or shrink the little white color showing around the icon?

Comment: you're using `.fa-twitter-square` in your example, Im using `.fa-twitter` and adding a box around it with css. see my demo link working as expected

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
#social-media-icons > a{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about how your answer helps.